# How do I align text, while ignoring a sibling image?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

Consider the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
         android:contentDescription="@string/pipboyImage_contentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/pipboyIcon"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pipboy"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the sample, I am trying to recreate an interface for a university exercise. The two relevant requirements are that we must use `LinearLayout`, and we must have compatibility for API 15. I am having trouble replicating the exact alignment of the text, and although I have confirmed that what I have so far is acceptable for the teachers definition of precisely replicating the provided interface, it is bugging me that I can't seem to figure out the correct way to align my text.

The text needs to be aligned to the centre. However, this alignment does not appear to acknowledge the image that is placed directly to the left of it. In the example, the text is perfectly aligned to the centre of the screen. In my example, the best I can get is to align the text to the centre of the remaining space after setting up the image.

[image: What I have vs What I am trying to do]

I have played around with `android:layout_weight`, eventually resting at a weight of 1 for the image and a weight of 4 for the text. At best, I end up with the same layout I have, now. I have also played around with `android:layout_gravity`, but all I seem to be able to do is move my alignment further away from what I intend.

Doing some research, online, it has been suggested that I use `RelativeLayout`. This is not an option, as the teacher has insisted we only use `LinearLayout`.One student suggested using `android:paddingLeft`. This is definitely an option, but I feel this would not give perfect orientation. It would simply 'mimic' the desired layout in the environment I am testing in.

I am also concerned about the use of `android:textAlignment="center"`, as this reports support of API 17, and we were specifically told to use support for API 15. Once again, failure to fix this slight misalignment will not lose me marks, so I am not concerned that I am simply not correctly implementing it 'to specification'. That said, the example was provided 'to specification', so I am curious as to how this has been performed using API 15 support and `LinearLayout`.

***How do I align text in a fashion that ignores sibling objects, using only `LinearLayout` and enforcing API 15 compatibility?***

Comment: There is a way if your image size is static you can use drawabeLeft of TextView. Try it and give drawablePadding to TextView.

Comment: @RameshKumar, I have explored `drawableLeft` based off your comment, but intellisense tells me it does not exist in the context, and it errors immediately on trying to implement it. I can find reference to it being used on *buttons*. Perhaps this is the result of my image not having a static size, but for the purpose of trying to create a layout that displays the same across varied displays, I'm not sure I *can* use static image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired alignment using the alternate answer posted, regarding a phantom view to balance out the image. However, while the author insists that it should work *as is* without any additional weight, I found that I still needed to play with the weight in order to reach the desired alignment.

This is my final layout, tweaked to give the desired result, in the example image I post with my question.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_headerLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_pipboyIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/pipboy"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_headerText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/main_headerCounterBalance"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

As a side note, I found a question on here that addressed the use `android:layout_weight` with `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`, advising that `weight` requires the corresponding dimension to be set to `0dp`, else the resulting size will *compound* with the dimensions given by `wrap_content` or `match_parent`. Sure enough, setting the desired `weight` to `0dp` gave me a crisper alignment, and I have since noticed straighter alignment in the text displayed through the above `.xml`.

I was also able to use `android:gravity="center"` instead of `android:textAlignment`, which gives the same centered alignment, without raising the warnings of incompatibility with the desired API 15.

Comment: This solution works. Only problem is that position of ImageView will have some change (distance from left bounds) with change in screen size.

Comment: Yes. It is having some small change in distance from left. This is because the total weightSum here is 6(1+4+1) & when going forward with larger screens, each of these parts becomes larger in width. So the ImageView will get centered in that space allocated & hence it will be little left from screen.

Comment: I can somewhat understand why. Even so, on up to 7" it is not noticeable, and it aligns a lot better with the addition of weight than without.

Comment: No probs if it fixes your requirement. I don't know why my answer was not working on your end. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this . It may work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/app_name_full"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" 
    android:src="@drawable/app_icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your icon in place of my icon.

Comment: you can resize it manually or put in other folder of drawable in res folder.

Comment: It appears resizing it manually actually resizes the layout, not the image, itself. I did not think it important to mention, but we have already been told not to use direct values in layout size. I created a placeholder icon image to try this with default image size, but once again, it all defaults to center. I am still left with the alignment as shown in ***what my layout looks like*** instead of ***what I want my layout to look like***.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have downvoted because the answer you provided did not seem to help my *unique* situation at all, but trying it out has lead me to try an alternate solution, which appears to work. This answer might still be valid for other users, so have a +1, instead.

Comment: thank you. You can try with relative layout too.see my updated answer.put your res

Answer (score 1):

Put a dummy `View` & set its width & height same as `ImageView`. Try

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pipboyIcon"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pipboy"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Exercise 2 Going mad"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OR**

Something ugly is to set negative margin to your `TextView`. Also remove `android:textAlignment` & add `android:gravity`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

> Note : This will work for small text's. If length is long, this will
>   overlap the image.

Comment: Beat me to the post, but the negative padding is how I did it. It works well for my scenario, as the text is small. The "phantom image" solution is very helpful, though. I can't believe I didn't think of it!

Comment: @Timelord64 Sometimes putting something extra leads to the result ;-)

Comment: For the point of practice, I converted it to instead include the extra view. While it does not work *immediately*, re-implementing `android:layout_weight`  fixes it to work quite well. I set the images to a weight of 1, and the text to a weight of 9, for my desired layout. Cheers!

Comment: @Timelord64 The edit you have by removing layout_weight won't work. weight makes the 3rd dummy view inside the screen bounds. If we remove that, the dummy view goes outside screen bounds & text won't be aligned as required.

Comment: in that case, could you add weight to the other elements? Without weight in the other elements (image and empty view), and width set to 0 (image, empty view and text), this example does not work.

Comment: No, the width of other 2 views remains 40dp as in the question & only ImageView weight is required. Also, setting weight '9' to ImageView & '1' to other 2 views will look different with larger space consumed by those 2 views if screen size is big.

Comment: If you insist. As I stated previously, this did not work until I added the weight to them.

Comment: I tested the xml I posted in my device & it works as expected. I can share screenshot if required. can you share screenshot of what you are getting by copying the same code as in my answer??

Comment: I'm not really bothered reverting my project again, just to show you it did not work for me. The text was drawn off and to the right, after a direct copy-paste. I have posted a copy-paste of what I have, now (save replacing some value references), which gives the exact center I was looking for. Since that was the code that worked for me, I have resubmitted it as the confirmed answer.